# After deploying asp.net mvc app to azure, the sql database data is missing

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have tables such as AspNetUsers and AspNetUserRoles but they're empty unless I create a new user on the website itself (but I have users and roles when I deploy via localhost).

If I deploy/publish with "execute code first migrations" checked I get some sort of database error when I try to log in. So I have to leave it unchecked for the website to work.

Is there a way I can copy the data from my databases in Visual Studio to the databases hosted (both can be viewed in visual studio). I just want the admin role function associated with an account as I've no way to create the admin role via the website.

Thank you

Comment: `I get some sort of database error` Any more details you can share?

Comment: You should consider seeding the required data instead of copying. This way you prevent the issue. You shouldn't have to copy data everytime you change the location of your app.

Comment: For any others having this problem in the future, I had this workaround which worked:

In your azure portal, in the left menu, go to "SQL databases", then click your database, then go to "Data explorer (preview)", then open the "Tables" folder and you can select one of them and then "Edit Data (Preview) up the top, and then i just "Create New Row" and entered the rows from my local databases manually

Comment: Script your migrations or use [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt).